# How to save parsnip/agua based H2O object and retrieve it again

Tags: r, h2o, tidymodels, parsnip

I have the following [script using tidymodels' agua](https://agua.tidymodels.org/articles/auto_ml.html) package:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(agua)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
h2o_start()

data(concrete)
set.seed(4595)
concrete_split <- initial_split(concrete, strata = compressive_strength)
concrete_train <- training(concrete_split)
concrete_test <- testing(concrete_split)

# run for a maximum of 120 seconds
auto_spec <-
  auto_ml() %>%
  set_engine("h2o", max_runtime_secs = 120, seed = 1) %>%
  set_mode("regression")

normalized_rec <-
  recipe(compressive_strength ~ ., data = concrete_train) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

auto_wflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(auto_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(normalized_rec)

auto_fit <- fit(auto_wflow, data = concrete_train)
saveRDS(auto_fit, file = "test.h2o.auto_fit.rds") #save the object
h2o_end()
```

There I tried to save the `auto_fit` object into a file.
But when I tried to retrieve it and use it to predict test data:

```
h2o_start()
auto_fit <- readRDS("test.h2o.auto_fit.rds")
predict(auto_fit, new_data = concrete_test)
```

I got an error:

```
Error in `h2o_get_model()`:
! Model id does not exist on the h2o server.
```

What's the way to go about it?

The expected result is:

```
predict(auto_fit, new_data = concrete_test)
#> # A tibble: 260 × 1
#>    .pred
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  40.0
#>  2  43.0
#>  3  38.2
#>  4  55.7
#>  5  41.4
#>  6  28.1
#>  7  53.2
#>  8  34.5
#>  9  51.1
#> 10  37.9
#> # … with 250 more rows
```

---

**Update**

After following Simon Couch advice

```
auto_fit <- fit(auto_wflow, data = concrete_train)
auto_fit_bundle <- bundle(auto_fit)
saveRDS(auto_fit_bundle, file = "test.h2o.auto_fit.rds") #save the object
h2o_end()

# to reload
h2o_start()
auto_fit_bundle <- readRDS("test.h2o.auto_fit.rds")
auto_fit <- unbundle(auto_fit_bundle)
predict(auto_fit, new_data = concrete_test)

rank_results(auto_fit)
```

I got this error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("rank_results") : 
  no applicable method for 'rank_results' applied to an object of class "c('H2ORegressionModel', 'H2OModel', 'Keyed')"
```

Comment: Do you need the `h2o_start` and `h2o_end`?

Answer (score 7):

Some model objects in R require *native serialization* methods to be saved and reloaded from file—h2o objects (and thus the tidymodels objects that wrap them) are an example of one that does.

The tidymodels and vetiver teams at Posit recently collaborated on a package, [bundle](https://rstudio.github.io/bundle), that provides a consistent interface to native serialization methods. The docs on h2o are [here](https://rstudio.github.io/bundle/reference/bundle_h2o.html).

```r
library(bundle)
```

In short, you will want to `bundle()` the object you're preparing to save, save it with the usual `saveRDS()`, and then, in your new session, `loadRDS()` and `unbundle()` the loaded-in object. The output of `unbundle()` is your ready-to-go model object. :)

```r
# to save:
auto_fit <- fit(auto_wflow, data = concrete_train)
auto_fit_bundle <- bundle(auto_fit)
saveRDS(auto_fit_bundle, file = "test.h2o.auto_fit.rds") #save the object
h2o_end()
```

```r
# to reload
h2o_start()
auto_fit_bundle <- readRDS("test.h2o.auto_fit.rds")
auto_fit <- unbundle(auto_fit_bundle)
predict(auto_fit, new_data = concrete_test)
```

Comment: Thanks. But, after `unbundle`, although `predict()` works, these two don't: `rank_results(auto_fit)` and `tidy(auto_fit)`. Please advice.

Comment: Does `bundle(` accept `c(` input?